# force numeric argument to function to have 2 decimal places

Tags: r, function, arguments

Is it possible, in an R function, to require that a numeric argument be provided with a certain number of decimal places. 
I would like to have something like:

```
foo <- function(x) {
  if(x has two decimal places) {
  do something
  }else{
  print("Error, please provide the number with two decimal places. Ex: 2010.01")
  }
}

foo(2010.1)
Error... 

foo(2010.10)
works
```

Context: I am writing a [package](https://github.com/lucasmation/microdadosBrasil) with a set of import functions for different datasets. There is a common numeric argument ( t, for "period") to all functions. However the frequency varies between datasets (yearly, quarterly and monthly). So I was thinking of having the user provide the year-month as a numeric variable with two decimal places. Jan 2010 would be t=2010.01. I want to stop the user from inadvertently writing 2010.1 for Jan 2010.

Also, let me know if you think this strategy is bound for trouble. The idea wat that a numeric argument for "period" would me more intuitive and less error pronto then a string one, but maybe it is not worth it.

Comment: you could use function (Ndec ) to count the no of decimal.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `grepl` to check for the correct pattern:

```
grepl("^[0-9]{4}\\.[0-9]{2}$", "2010.11")
TRUE
grepl("^[0-9]{4}\\.[0-9]{2}$", "2010.1")
FALSE
grepl("^[0-9]{4}\\.[0-9]{2}$", "2010.001")
FALSE
```

So your condition would look like:

```
if(grepl("^[0-9]{4}\\.[0-9]{2}$", as.character(x))) {
  do something
else stop("wrong entry")
```

Comment: I tried implementing your solution but it does not work. foo(2010.10) returns the error message. I think 2010.10 may be getting evaluated to 2010.1 before entering the conditional inside the function. Also, 2010.001 is not being considered a wrong entry

Comment: I edited the regex to fix the second (and related situations) by adding the anchors, "^" and "$". Your first scenario is more difficult to solve. One method would be to force users to enter the value as a character and throw an error with `stop` if they don't.